# How to idiomatically construct struct with heap references?

Tags: rust

So i'm currently stumped on initializing a `struct` by loading a `Yaml` file into heap memory:

```
extern crate yaml_rust;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs;
use yaml_rust::{Yaml, YamlLoader};

struct Petrovich {
    middlename: Yaml,
    firstname: Yaml,
    lastname: Yaml
}

impl  Petrovich {

    fn new() -> Petrovich {

        // Open Rules File (Panics on error)
        let mut f = fs::File::open("./src/rules.yml").unwrap();
        // Create String Buffer and Read to it
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        f.read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        // Pass Buffer to Yaml and unwrap
        let rules: &Yaml = &YamlLoader::load_from_str(&buffer).unwrap()[0];

        // Return Petrovich with preloaded rules
        Petrovich { 
            middlename: rules["middlename"],
            firstname: rules["firstname"],
            lastname: rules["lastname"]
        }
    }
}
```

However i get a `cannot move out of indexed content` error. How do i tackle this?

EDIT: I am using `yaml-rust` for this and have a file `rules.yml` with `firstname`, `lastname` and `middlename` fields included within `./src`

Source can be found here: https://github.com/Latrasis/petrovich-rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Yaml` is `Clone`, so you can simply call .clone() on the reference to copy its contents "out":

```
    Petrovich { 
        middlename: rules["middlename"].clone(),
        firstname: rules["firstname"].clone(),
        lastname: rules["lastname"].clone(),
    }
```

I prefer this to the accepted solution because the data being copied is small and it doesn't rely on the implementation of `yaml::Hash`. Cloning an entire document tree might be another matter.

You may have an argument here for a feature to be added to yaml-rust. Moving an element out of a tree seems like a reasonable request, but the API doesn't support it directly.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to move out of a borrowed pointer (because `rules[str]` returns a `&Yaml`), but that's not legal. We need to use functions that allow us to move a value out of the main `Yaml` object. This will alter the main `Yaml` object, but that's OK here, since we will discard it by the end of the function.

First, we need to understand what indexing with a string does. [The implementation](https://github.com/chyh1990/yaml-rust/blob/840a560e0e20cffd744251c1d9d245029145de39/src/yaml.rs#L262-L272) only returns a significant value if the value is a hash and gets to the underlying value by constructing a `Yaml::String` value to index the hash.

The `Yaml::Hash` variant wraps a [`BTreeMap<Yaml, Yaml>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html). The library provides the `as_hash` convenience method to access it, but this only gives an immutable pointer. We need to use pattern matching to get a mutable pointer.

Next, we'll use the [`remove` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.remove) on the `BTreeMap` to extract the value associated with the keys that interest us.

Here's the result:

```
impl Petrovich {
    fn new() -> Petrovich {
        use yaml_rust::yaml::Hash as YamlHash;

        // Open Rules File (Panics on error)
        let mut f = fs::File::open("./src/rules.yml").unwrap();
        // Create String Buffer and Read to it
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        f.read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        // Pass Buffer to Yaml and unwrap
        let rules: &mut Yaml = &mut YamlLoader::load_from_str(&buffer).unwrap()[0];
        let rules: &mut YamlHash = match *rules {
            Yaml::Hash(ref mut hash) => hash,
            _ => panic!("not a hash"),
        };

        // Return Petrovich with preloaded rules
        Petrovich {
            middlename: rules.remove(&Yaml::String("middlename".into())).unwrap(),
            firstname: rules.remove(&Yaml::String("firstname".into())).unwrap(),
            lastname: rules.remove(&Yaml::String("lastname".into())).unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code will panic in situations in which your original code (if it worked) wouldn't, as you would get `BadValue`s instead. I'll leave it to you to handle errors as you need.

Answer (score 3):

I recently implemented [Serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) support for YAML: https://github.com/dtolnay/serde-yaml

Serde is a powerful serialization framework that allows Rust structs to be converted to and from a variety of formats: JSON, YAML, XML, TOML, MessagePack, Bincode.

Here is a complete working example that demonstrates deserializing a Petrovich from a file rules.yml:

```
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_yaml;

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Petrovich {
    middlename: String,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String
}

fn main() {
    let f = std::fs::File::open("test.yml").unwrap();
    let p: Petrovich = serde_yaml::from_reader(f).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&p.firstname, "latrasis");
}
```

Serde supports arbitrarily complicated nested types, so the struct that you deserialize could contain vectors, maps, or other structs inside and the code would remain just as simple.

Comment: Does this work on stable Rust versions, or only nightly?